# How can I do a search and replace from some text to a second or third instance of the to text?

Tags: regex, notepad++

My bad if that question is worded janky. I hope it can be edited if needed. I couldn't figure out how to word it better. Anyway.

I have some text lines like this:

```
1.  "C:\OverPark\Casting\What You Are\L - New Takes\Justice and Truth\Dialogue\The Blessing Tree.wav" (77.3 MB)

2.  "C:\OverPark\Casting\What You Are\L - New Takes\Infinity\External\Momha.wav" (34.9 MB)

3.  "C:\OverPark\Casting\What You Are\L - New Takes\Intellect and Love\Music\The Most High.wav" (37.8 MB)
```

I need to replace every line from after the numbers and their dot, over to the 6th backslash.

I know how to select from somewhere, to the end of line.
I know how to search from somewhere, to a certain text.

But what if, like in this case, there are many characters that are identical to the character/s you need to end with in between the selection?

I can't use something like e/M for the to command because the folders before and after the backslash are constantly changing in the file path. But the amount of slashes *seem* to be the same. Sometimes I need to simply remove it, sometimes I need to replace it with something.

How can I tell the search to skip a certain number of backslashes or something similar? Or maybe there is a better way to approach this?

It should look like this in the end, unless I replace it with something.

```
1.Dialogue\The Blessing Tree.wav" (77.3 MB)

2.External\Momha.wav" (34.9 MB)

3.Music\The Most High.wav" (37.8 MB)
```

I can achieve this in two steps by first skipping over a certain number of backslash instances in the line, like so:

```
^(?:.*?\\){5}
```

I can replace it with a unique character that does not exist in the line, then do another search and replace from the beginning of the line to that unique character. I just wanted to see if it can be done in one pass. If I could, I'd like to use a single command to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for all input and help!

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry. I should have added that to the question. Getting the hang of things. I have updated the question. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Does replacing [`3\.\K.+\\(?=Music)`](https://regex101.com/r/SEkPsz/1) with nothing works for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining.

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! It only addressed that single line, starting with 3 though. I am sorry again I did not clarify that the numbers at the beginning change, and I need to do multiple lines at once. I have updated the question again. Please bare with me. I am learning how important it is to be very precise when asking and explaining things. :)

Comment: If you do give me a solution, if possible can you explain to me whats happening in your command? I don't understand everything clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match something 6 times, repeat it exactly 6 times:

```
^\d+\.          # At the start of a line, match an integer and a dot,
\K              # then forfeit that and start the match anew;
(?:             # from that position, match
  [^\\]+\\      # one or more non-backslash then a backslash,
){6}            # collectively repeated 6 times.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SEkPsz/2).

You can also replace everything up to the second-to-last backslash, if you so choose:

```
^\d+\.          # Idem;
\K              # 
.+\\            # from that position, match a sequence of characters that ends with a backslash
(?=             # which must be followed by
  [^\\]+\\      # a level, a backslash,
  [^\\]+$       # and another level at the end of line.
)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SEkPsz/3).

Note that a "level" here is simply a sequence of non-backslashes; it fits just well for this particular use case but might not do the trick in another.

Your *Search Mode* should look something like this (*Replace with* is empty):

[image: Regular expression: checked; Dot matches new line: unchecked]

Comment: Wow. Thank you my friend. I get the \K to forfeit and restart. Nice. I was wondering about that. Thank you for providing 2 approaches as well. Taking note of both, using the first one at the moment. And yes, It works great! I noticed that many of my lines have two spaces at the beginning of the line before the number. This command does not work on those lines, I wonder why. But it works. I just have to make sure the line does not start with a space (which is easy to correct.) Is there an explanation for why that is?

Comment: @hummieru `^` matches only at the very start of the line. If you want to allow leading whitespaces as well, change it to `^\h*`: [`^\h*\d+\.\K.+\\(?=[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/SEkPsz/4).

Comment: Yep. Flawless. Thank you again!